# Adding 2 text boxes using JS

Tags: javascript, html

can someone show me where I'm going wrong please?

I have 2 text boxes... When the user clicks Calculate I want the paragraph with ID myResult to display the result of the 2 text boxes.

```js
<script>
function sum() {
       var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('num1').value;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('num2').value;
       if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
           txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
       if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
           txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('myResult').value = result;
       }
   }
   </script>
```

```html
    <input id='num1' type="text">
    <input id='num2' type="text">
    
    <p id='myResult'>0</p>  
    
    <input name="b1" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="sum();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you try to set your result to a `value` of `<p>`, which doesn't exist. You should set instead the `innerText`:

```
document.getElementById('myResult').innerText = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
document.getElementById('myResult').innerHTML = result;
```

.value is an attribute of input, but not an attribute of p element, so it should give you an error there

I think .textContent should work too.

Answer (score 0):

a p tag doesnt have a "value" if you want to access the text you have to use .innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('myResult').innerHTML= result;
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your **isNaN** to **Number.isNaN**.
Secondly, you need to insert the value in innerHTML in your ID **myResult**

```
function sum() {
       var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('num1').value;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('num2').value;
       if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
           txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
       if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
           txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       if (!Number.isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('myResult').innerHTML = result;
       }
   }
```